# If you're LD_PRELOAD'ing nVidia GL

Tags: arch-linux, tor

I am trying to install tor and config it on arch linux 
that is my steps.

1) install tor.

2) install proxychains-ng

3) change config file `/etc/proxychains.conf`
in that file I accessed `dynamic_chain` and comment `strict_chain` also added on the buttom `socks5  127.0.0.1 9050`

4) run as root `proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com`

5) I got this error `Sandbox: unexpected multithreading found; this prevents using namespace sandboxing.  (If you're LD_PRELOAD'ing nVidia GL: that's not necessary for Gecko.)`

The question is what does that error mean and how to fix it?

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you want to use proxychains? Firefox supports SOCKS v4/v5 natively(Settings->Advanced->Network->Settings), so there is no need to use proxychains.

With that said,
the warning itsself is triggered [here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/sandbox/linux/common/SandboxInfo.cpp#60), that is whenever there is more than one thread running it gets printed. Since proxychains-ng itsself is multithreaded, this warning is expected and you can't avoid it without changing the code.

Comment: still, how to fix that?

Comment: You can't. Firefox assumes that there is an issue if you have multiple threads at the point the check is performed, so there is probably a good reason why the check is performed. You'll either need to change the check to account for proxychains threads(difficult), live without namespace sandboxing or use Firefox's native SOCKS support.